# sp_user_display_name always returns canonical name, even when user is loaded

Tags: spotify, libspotify

Hello Spotify community =)  I've been beating my head against this for a while.  When I ask *libspotify* for the owner of a playlist via `sp_playlist_owner`, I am never able to get the user's display name out from `sp_user_display_name`.

In the API, it mentions that the display name is only available after the user has been loaded.  Specifically, this should be when `sp_user_is_loaded` returns `true`.  However, I have found this to not be the case.

I have hooked into every available playlist callback in an attempt to catch when the user is loaded, and then output both the canonical and display names.  I am doing this for a playlist where I know the canonical and display names of the owner are different.

- In the case of a fresh start (deleting the settings directory before invoking `sp_session_create`), I initially get the Spotify log message `UserCache::initiateGetUsers() will query for 1 users`.  Subsequent callbacks then indicate that the user has been loaded, but the canonical name is always returned.
- In the case of a restart (where the playlist data is loaded from disk), I don't get the log message mentioned above, and the user is initially indicated as loaded.  But again, the same problem.  I am only ever given the canonical username.

Is this a bug in the API, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the full display name is only available in libspotify for the currently logged-in user, and then only if they logged in with Facebook credentials.

Comment: Okay, I can live with that while I wait for the new JSON-based API. I trust that will be able to supply the display names for other users?