# sp_user_display_name returns username and not displayname

Tags: c, delphi, libspotify

I`m trying to get Display name with sp_user_display_name, but I get cronical name only. I see that Social_manager.bnk only has cronical name on all my facebook friends. Have tried to turn on scrobbling to facebook and scrobling to spotify, but no luck. I have tried to log in with spotify credentials and facebook credentials. Is this a bug in the libspotify API?

This is the function for calling sp_user_display_name:

```
function TUser.GetName: String;
begin
Result:= UTF8ToString(sp_user_display_name(sp_session_user(spotify.fSession)));
end;
```

But it results the same as:

```
function TUser.GetCanonicalName: String;
begin
Result:= UTF8ToString(sp_user_canonical_name(sp_session_user(spotify.fSession)));
end;
```

Comment: It would be helpful to share code. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: updated with a code snippet

Comment: Did you see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23797162/62576)?

Comment: yes,but it does not answer my question. I`m trying to get the logged in user`s displayname. And i`m logged in using facebooks credentials. After further rescearch. i see that is_scrobbling_possible(for facebook) results false. How to get this to result true. Have facebook made any new changes to Graph API, making libspotify unable to fetch displaynames?

Comment: If you look at api.h in the include/libspotify folder and search for `sp_session_set_social_credentials` which is below `sp_session_is_scrobbling_possible` you can see the following in the comments: ` * Set the user's credentials with a social provider.
 * Currently this is only relevant for LastFm` So it seems it doesn't work for FB? Would be weird imo though.

Comment: Tried `sp_session_set_social_credentials`, but no luck.